# Is there a way to set up some sort of flag or tag to a command instead of referring to its full name in terminal?

Tags: command-line, apt, package-management, dpkg, packaging

I'm trying to figure out if theres a way to rename or use some sort of tag that points to a package instead of having to write the whole name of the package in the command line? because some packages have very long names so I don't want to be typing it every time.

Comment: Don't you have tab completion? Which shell are you using?

Comment: If you don't have tab completion, [use variables](http://askubuntu.com/a/751211/158442).

Comment: Why do you need to type a *package*'s name so often anyway? Are you sure you really mean *package*, and not something else such as *command*?

Comment: Sorry i'm new in linux, and i'm learning as i go with it. Yeah i totally meant command, but again the tab completion was really helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use shell autocompletion. Using bash (ubuntu user default shell) just do your command write part of the package name then press <kbd>TAB</kbd>

```
apt-cache showpkg firef<TAB>
```

In this case the shells line editor should complete to

```
apt-cache showpkg firefox
```

if the match is ambiguous (i.e. if there are multiple packages that start with `firef`) it should show a list of potential matches